# How to implement role based aurelia routing

Tags: routes, roles, aurelia

I am having all my routes in one .ts file, and my main.ts is coming to first route that is login in that routes file. where i don't want to load the left menu, and after authorization i will route to either customer or support member. there my routes in left menu have to be populated as per role given. how to implement his scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Navigation in Aurelia is based on a set of javascript objects that you pass to the router configuration. There's nothing that doesn't allow you to extend those objects in order to contain additional information regarding roles. So you should be able to add a role field.

```
{
  route: ['', 'todo/list'],
  name: 'ToDoList',
  moduleId: './to-do/list',
  nav: true,
  title: 'To Do List',
  authRoute: true,
  role: 'TaskAdmin'
}
```

Then when you create your template for navigation you'll want to show based on the role and navigation item.

```
<li repeat.for="navItem of router.navigation" class="${showNav(navItem) ? 'showNav' : 'hideNav'}">
  <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
<li>
```

The function that needs to be included in the corresponding js code file:

```
showNav(navItem) {
  return localStorage.getItem("role") === navItem.role;
}
```

There are several ways to set up authentication which even includes the ability to build your own, but I'll point you to a few.

[Blog Post on Aurelia-Auth](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/08/24/jwt-authentication-in-aurelia/)

[Aurelia-Authentication documentation](http://aurelia-authentication.spoonx.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I made a (non-ts) gist of a simple role-based navigation, inspired by Saqib's answer.

Perhaps it will help someone: [aurelia role-based routing](https://gist.github.com/danbergman/f2861eff3f65d694542bb2f8ff8bf63d)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do: Filter the items in the Nav bar so that they are shown/hidden based on the roles, using a ValueConverter.  The value filter filters out the navbar items that the should not be shown.

```
export class AuthorizedValueConverter {
    toView(routes: Array<string>, select: Array<string>) {
        if (select && select.length > 0) {
            return routes.filter((route: any) => {

                if (route.config.roles) {
                    return route.config.roles.some((role: string) => {
                        return select.indexOf(role) > -1;
                    });
                } else
                    return [];
            });
        }
        else
            return [];
    }
}
```

The nav bar:

app.html

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation  | authorized: roles " class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''} nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</span></a>
</li>
```

Then you just need to expose the roles in the ViewMode:

app.ts:

```
//This is used by the navigation bar to filter out roles that the user is not authorized to view
get roles() {
    return this.accountService.currentUser.appRoles;
}
```